# Associative property of free product of groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

I am reading Algebraic Topology by Allen Hatcher (available online at http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) and at line 1 of page 42, it reads:

*"... because of the relation $L_{gg'}=L_gL_g'$, ..."*

But it seems to me that in the previous page, he only shows that $L_{gg'}=L_gL_g'$ if there exists $G_{\alpha}$ with $g, g'\in G_{\alpha}$. If $g$ and $g'$ are in different $G_{\alpha}$'s, how to prove the relation $L_{gg'}=L_gL_g'$?

The context is quoted below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: (-1) You should make your question self contained.

Comment: Thanks @Student, it has been edited. Now is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ and $g'$ are in different $G_\alpha$, then by definition of $L$, $L(gg') = L_gL_{g'}$. If $g$ and $g'$ are in the same $G_\alpha$, $L(gg') = L_{gg'} = L_gL_{g'}$  by the formula. So for all $g$, $g'$, $L(gg') = L_gL_{g'}$, i.e. $L$ preserves the group operation.

Comment: If $g$ and $g'$ are in different $G_\alpha$, then by definition of $L$, $L(gg')(g_1\cdots g_n)=(gg')(g_1\cdots g_n)$ while $ (L_gL_{g'})(g_1\cdots g_n)=g(g'g_1\cdots g_n)$. Why are they the same?

Comment: Because concatenation of sequences is an associative operation.

Comment: @LeeMosher, I would agree that they are equal if $g'$ and $g_1$ are not in the same $G_{\alpha}$, but what if they are? Is it still obvious?

Comment: @zuriel That's not the definition of $L$. The definition of $L$ is $L(g_1...g_n) = L_{g_1}L_{g_2}\cdots L_{g_n}$ where $g_1\cdots g_n$ is a reduced word. The definition of $L_g$ is $L_g(g_1\cdots g_n) = gg_1\cdots g_n$, but this only applies when $g \in G_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, which isn't the case for $gg'$ with $g$, $g'$ in different $G_\alpha$.

Comment: @user73985, now I see!! Thank you very much!